# How do i fix the error "ffmpeg was not found." in my discord bot?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, audio-player

I am currently trying to make my discord bot play a youtube audio from a URL. However, I can't pass the error "ffmpeg was not found". I have tried to use different solutions but nothing has worked. My code currently looks like this:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

@bot.command(brief="Plays a single video, from a youtube URL")
async def play(ctx, url):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("{} is not connected to a voice channel".format(ctx.message.author.name))
        return
    else:
        global channel_player
        channel_player = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel_player.connect()
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice.is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['url']
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        voice.is_playing()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Already playing song")
        return
```

I am relatively new to coding so if you have any other suggestions on top of (hopefully) the solution to the problem, feel free!

I am relatively new to coding so if you have any other suggestions on top of (hopefully) the solution to the problem, feel free!

I have as I said tried a few different other approaches but nothing has worked. The one that seemed to almost work was to download ffmpeg through libx264 and create files that python could be directed to.

I also tried downloadeing the most recent version of ffmpeg and 7zip to extract it.

Comment: Did you install ffmpeg?   The Python ffmpeg module is just a wrapper that executes the `ffmpeg` command line tool.  It has to be able to find ffmpeg on the path, or by specifying the exact location as a configuration parameter.

Comment: @TimRoberts as I said I downloaded it and tried to extract it through 7ZIP, as well as compile it through linx264. However, since I'm relatively new, I didn't really understand how i was supposed to use it.

Comment: You need to add the folder to your path.  https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-windows